# How to use HSTS only for some subdomains

Tags: .net, iis, content-security-policy, response-headers, hsts

I know that **HSTS is a top-level header**, but I have a multi-tenant application (consider something like WordPress) in which all tenants are totally separated and have no idea of a similar tenant

Each of them can **use SSL or do not use any certificate**, so I can have 10 tenant which uses HTTPS and 10 tenant which uses HTTP

HTTPS://AAA.example.com

HTTPS://BBB.example.com

HTTPS://CCC.example.com

HTTP://DDD.example.com

HTTP://EEE.example.com

HTTP://FFF.example.com

all tenants are in **example.com** and are totally individual instances of the same application, and all of them include all the resources that they have (images scripts ..., in their instance)

so If I enable HSTS for example.com and add includeSubDomains, **all the HTTP tenants will face serious issues and won't load**

So **how can I enable HSTS only and only for subdomains that are using HTTPS**?

I am using .NET + IIS stack, and consider that I have a flag that let me know I can add HSTS response-header to this specific tenant or not

I already checked these

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-5.3

https://serverfault.com/questions/482350/can-i-turn-on-hsts-for-1-subdomain

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/hsts-and-expired-certificate-gotcha/140050/5

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124400/may-hsts-block-access-to-your-site-when-you-renew-your-ssl-certificate

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112493/hsts-on-a-subdomain-with-includesubdomains

Comment: you will have to declare hsts on all of the appropriate subdomains

Comment: @DanielA.White can you tell me how to do that? sperately

Comment: it really depends on _your_ application and how its configured

Comment: you might also consider a wildcard cert and allow all of your tenants to benefit

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for the help, because of several reasons I cannot allow all subdomains to use HTTPS (and that is why in the RFC you have the option to enable the subdomain) in my case I have a setting to check every individual request and check what is the tenant. the main issue is that HSTS is a top-level header, so if I add it to subdomain AA, then subdomain EE forcibly uses HSTS, can you please provide an example and show me how is it possible to create a WHITE or BLACK list of subdomain to allow or forbid the HSTS?

Comment: Don’t say include subdomains in example.com